# Ubuntu 18.04 stuck in boot after starting Gnome Display Manager on Nvidia Graphics not 10 reputaion not 50 reputation

Tags: boot, gnome, 19.04

Do to this bad practice of extreme reputations for answering and commenting, I have to create a new question. Sorry for that.

The problem seems to come from the "install third party software....." option.

I tested with Ubuntu 19.04 and the first time I was unable to login in, so I put the USB drive again and this time I didn't click "install third party wifi and etc....", erased and installed again and I had no problem.

Comment: Please only use current versions, Ubuntu 19.04 is EoL or end of life. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases Repositories are closed so updates not available.

Comment: When I used the latest version of Ubuntu 19.10, I had similar problem and a lot of the features were not working correctly. This is why I wanted to skip Ubuntu 19.10.